# Expected Value of Product of Two Dice

Tags: probability

You have 2 dice. The $ you gain is the product of the 2 dice. If you would like, you can reroll 1 dice. What is the expected value and optimal strategy?

As the two rolls are independent, we know that the standard expected product is $E(X)E(X) = 3.5^2 = 12.25$. Hence, if we roll the 2 dice and observe a product between 1 and 12, we should reroll the minimum of the two dice. Otherwise, if the product is greater than 12, we keep our score. Constructing the sample space with 2 dice, we see that $\frac{13}{36}$ of the outcomes are greater than 12 (with average $\frac{291}{13}$).

Hence, for the $\frac{23}{36}$ outcomes smaller than 12, we reroll with the expectation of the new product being $3.5^2$. Hence, the expected value of the game is:

$E = \frac{23}{36} * (\frac{7}{2})^2 + \frac{13}{36} * \frac{291}{13} = 15.9$

I am not sure if this is the right answer, but I have doubts of my methodology. For example, if we roll a 6 and a 3, then by my methodology I would keep the score as 18 is greater than 12. However, since we have a fixed 6, we can use our reroll on the lower number, 3, to get an expected new product of $6 * 3.5 = 21$. So, should we reroll in this case? Does this strategy make more sense? If so, can you please provide an outline for the new calculation.

Comment: In your last paragraph, I think you have figured out why your previous answer is wrong, and also what criteria you need for a correct answer.

Comment: If you fix the 6 and preroll the other die, what is the expected value of the product? Do this for each of the possible dice rolls, and tabulate the results to figure out the expected value.